# JavaFX program loads too slow

Tags: javafx

The first appearance of the window when I run a JavaFX program takes too much time – ~700 ms. This is a noticeable latency.

**Does JavaFX can load faster?**

---

That I have:

I have a simple HelloWorld project created from Maven archetype `org.openjfx:javafx-archetype-simple:0.0.3`. I only added an additional class with PSVM that calls PSVM of the class that extends `Application` class:

```java
public class MainLauncher {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("MainLauncher...");
        App.main(args);
    }
}

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {...}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("App...");
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

`MainLauncher` is needed for creating uber-JAR with `maven-shade-plugin`.

I have used screen recording (60 FPS) to check how much time the application start takes.

When I run `java -jar app.jar` or `java -p ${JARS_AND_FOLDER_WITH_CLASSES} -m com.company/com.company.MainLauncher`, in other words – when I run `MainLauncher` class I get:

- at 0 ms I run the app
- at ~30-110 ms I see the console log
- at ~600-750 ms I see the window starts painting
- +30 ms for the window ends painting*

When I run `App` class, the behaviour is a bit another, but the total time is the same. In this case I see the log "`App...`" in console later:

- at 0 ms I run the app
- at ~550 ms I see the console log
- at ~600-750 ms I see the window starts painting
- +30 ms for the window ends painting*

*The window painting takes 2-3 frames (for 60 FPS):
 1. [Title bar + borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYHOO.png)
 2. [Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy62L.png)
 3. [Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFXn1.png)

Comment: Probably not, this is all including first initialisation of JavaFX itself and JVM warmup time. 700ms is not bad. Try measuring how long it takes to open a second, third, fourth window, that will probably go a lot faster.

Comment: In comparison with QT it is slow. It's okay for big program like IDE, but not for a little program that you open and close frequently like an image viewer. Even Electron starts faster (the first appearance of the window is at ~200 ms and +200-300 ms for content rendering).

Comment: Yes but comparing apples and oranges is pretty pointless.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest versions of Java some speed-up might be possible.
The key is Application Class Data Sharing. [Application class data sharing](https://blog.codefx.org/java/application-class-data-sharing/)
This can be activated via command line arguments of the java command.
Basically it stores all the initialization data somewhere and when the
application is launched a second time the whole initialization procedure
can be skipped.